# How to Post the values of dynamically added field in angular js to php?

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a form where dynamically fields are added.

```
$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
$scope.removeChoice = function(z)  
    {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
        $scope.choices.splice(z,1);
    };

    $scope.addNewChoice = function() 
    {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
        $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});


    };
```

The values are inserted correctly in the controller file when insert function is called. The inser function is as follows.

```
$scope.insert = function()
        {

            $scope.checklist_name = $scope.values.checklist_name;
            $scope.data =[];
            $scope.data = $scope.choices;

            //alert('companyId=='+$scope.app.company_id);

            $scope.item = [];
            var newItem = {};

            for( var i in $scope.choices)
            {
                newItem= $scope.choices[i];
                $scope.item.push(newItem);
            }

            console.log( "item",$scope.item);

            var fd = new FormData();



            fd.append('action', APP_ACTION.INSERT_CHECKLIST);

           fd.append('company_id', $scope.app.company_id);
            fd.append('user_id', $cookieStore.get('userData').id);
            fd.append('checkListName',$scope.checklist_name);
            fd.append('checkListData',$scope.item);

            httpCall.remoteCallPost($scope, $http, fd, function (record) 
            {
                alert('data========'+record.data);

            }, function (message) 
            {
                alert('Error');
            });
        }
```

The data in $scope.item is like this

```
[
0:{id: "choice1", number: "1", shortext: "1", longtext: "1", photo: true},
    1:{id: "choice2", number: "2", shortext: "2", longtext: "2"},
    2:{id: "choice3", number: "3", shortext: "3", longtext: "3"}
]
```

And when i receive the request in php backend i got the array like this

```
Array
(
    [action] => insertCheckList
    [company_id] => 2
    [user_id] => 13
    [checkListName] => sadasdsa
    [checkListData] => [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
)
```

My Question is how to access the datas that are coming as object or i am sendind the data in wrong way , if i am sending them in the wrong way then how to send the data in correct proper way ?

Comment: You need to serialize the data in Angular and then do json_decode in PHP to turn the string back into array.

Comment: @MattNewelski Can You explain a little bit or some coding

Comment: If you google "javascript object php post" it's literally the first result

Comment: @MattNewelski Thanks ...works...